# A mother of dragons

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, geography

> A mother of dragons, a sea-rimmed estate,
>   with flora and fauna in protected state.
>   A line that goes nearby the whole world equates;
>   I'm neighboured by flowers in land of the raids.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> the island of **Komodo** in Indonesia.

A mother of dragons, a sea-rimmed estate,

> That would be the [Komodo dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon). And Komodo is an island, hence "sea-rimmed".

with flora and fauna in protected state.

> The island is part of the [Komodo National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_National_Park).

A line that goes nearby the whole world equates;

> Komodo is about 8.5 degrees south of the equator. Don't know whether that counts as "nearby".

I'm neighboured by flowers in land of the raids.

> Nearby is the island of [Flores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flores), whose name means "flowers". I confess I'm not sure why "land of the raids"; I wondered whether perhaps "Flores" or "Sunda" or "Indonesia" has some such meaning, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Unsurprisingly a web search for `indonesia raids` turns up plenty, but the same would be true for any other country :-).

Comment: This is the intended answer. The last clue remains a mystery :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though this puzzle is already solved, I would like to add to the unsolved last clue.

Land of the raids refers to

> Flores is known to be an island of slave raiders, and Komodo dragons usually raid graves to hunt for dead bodies to eat. (Komodos are carnivores.)

Comment: This was actually referring to rot13(gjb Vaqbarfvna svyzf gvgyrq Gur Envq). In retrospect it was probably unfair to write it in lowercase.

Comment: Ah, yes, that works too, btw, I'm an Indonesian, so that was my first hunch

Comment: Well, my answer was the hunch